# Do there exist $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb{C}$ such that $ad-bc=1$ and $(|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+|d|^2)(|c|^2+|d|^2)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I can see there are no such real $a,b,c,d$. Because if there are $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $ad-bc=1$ and $(|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+|d|^2)(|c|^2+|d|^2)=1$, then $a=\cos\theta,b=\sin\theta,c=-\sin\theta,d=\cos\theta$. Then $(|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+|d|^2)(|c|^2+|d|^2)=2$.

But I cannot see whether there is a complex solution or not. Can anyone help me in this regard? Any kind of hint or idea will be beneficial. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: $ad-bc=1$ does not let you conclude that the numbers are sines and cosines of real numbers. For example, you could have $100, 1, 99, 1$.

Comment: Much less that they are the sine and cosine of the same angle.

Comment: You can show that if $z,w\in\mathbb C$ and $|zw|\geq1$ then $(|z|^2+|w|^2)|w|^2>1.$ Letting $z=a+bi, w=d+ci,$ you can show such real $a,b,c,d$ cannot exist. You might be able to finagle quaternions to proven the complex case has no solution, too.

Comment: For $~a,b,c,d \in \Bbb{R},$ $$(|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+|d|^2)(|c|^2+|d|^2)=1 \implies $$ $$|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+|d|^2 = |c|^2+|d|^2 \implies $$ $$|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 0 \implies a = 0 = b \implies ac - bd = 0.$$

Comment: Upon reflection, the previous comment apparently also holds, if $~a,b,c,d \in \Bbb{C}.$

Comment: @user2661923 Can you tell me how do you get $|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+|d|^2=|c|^2+|d|^2$?

Comment: Multiply both the LHS and RHS by $~\left(|c|^2 + |d|^2\right).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon Thomas Andrew’s idea: when $ad-bc=1$, note that $(c,d)\ne(0,0)$ and
$$
1=|ad-bc|^2=|\langle \overline{(a,b)},(-d,c)\rangle|^2
\le\|(a,b)\|_2^2\|(-d,c)\|_2^2=(|a|^2+|b|^2)(|c|^2+|d|^2).
$$
Therefore
$$
(|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+|d|^2)(|c|^2+|d|^2)
>(|a|^2+|b|^2)(|c|^2+|d|^2)\ge1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$. Then $1 = \det A = \det AA^\dagger = (|a|^2 + |b|^2) (|c|^2 + |d|^2) - |a\overline{c} + b\overline{d}|^2$. The latter term $T = |a\overline{c} + b\overline{d}|^2$ must obviously be zero, otherwise $1+T$ would still be less than the LHS of your second equation...

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}$. Since $\det A=1$, it has a singular value decomposition $USV^\ast$ where $S=\pmatrix{\sigma\\ &\sigma^{-1}}$ for some $\sigma>0$. Now let $|u_{21}|=\cos\theta$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left(|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+|d|^2\right)\left(|c|^2+|d|^2\right)\\
&=\|A\|_F^2\ \|e_2^TUSV^\ast\|_2^2\\
&=\|A\|_F^2\ \left\|\left(\sigma u_{21},\,\sigma^{-1}u_{22}\right)\right\|_2^2\\
&=\left(\sigma^2+\sigma^{-2}\right)\left(\sigma^2\cos^2\theta+\sigma^{-2}\sin^2\theta\right)\\
&=1+\sigma^4\cos^2\theta+\sigma^{-4}\sin^2\theta>1.
\end{aligned}
$$